# C# Linq-to-Sql - Should DataContext be disposed using IDisposable

Tags: linq-to-sql, datacontext, idisposable

I have several methods that deal with DB and all of them start by calling

```
FaierDbDataContext db = new FaierDbDataContext();
```

Since the Linq2Sql DataContext object implements IDisposable, should this be used with "using"?

```
using (FaierDbDataContext db = new FaierDbDataContext()) {
    // use db here
}
```

What are the implications of using it one way or another?

Comment: Also, a side note, for people using LINQ you shouldn't keep an instance variable of your datacontext for your data model class.  Instead, declare one every time you need to in your methods.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Unlike most types which implement
>   IDisposable, DataContext doesn't
>   really need disposing - at least not
>   in most cases. I asked Matt Warren
>   about this design decision, and here
>   was his response:
>
> There are a few reasons we implemented
>   IDisposable:
>
> - If application logic needs to hold onto an entity beyond when the
>     DataContext is expected to be used or
>     valid you can enforce that contract by
>     calling Dispose. Deferred loaders in
>     that entity will still be referencing
>     the DataContext and will try to use it
>     if any code attempts to navigate the
>     deferred properties. These attempts
>     will fail. Dispose also forces the
>     DataContext to dump its cache of
>     materialized entities so that a single
>     cached entity will not accidentally
>     keep alive all entities materialized
>     through that DataContext, which would
>     otherwise cause what appears to be a
>     memory leak.
> - The logic that automatically closes the DataContext connection can be
>     tricked into leaving the connection
>     open. The DataContext relies on the
>     application code enumerating all
>     results of a query since getting to
>     the end of a resultset triggers the
>     connection to close. If the
>     application uses IEnumerable's
>     MoveNext method instead of a foreach
>     statement in C# or VB, you can exit
>     the enumeration prematurely. If your
>     application experiences problems with
>     connections not closing and you
>     suspect the automatic closing behavior
>     is not working you can use the Dispose
>     pattern as a work around.

from the [source](http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=89)