# LINQ to SQL DB Connections not closing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I am using LINQ to SQL in an asp.net mvc application. I am calling stored procedures via ajax calls.

The active connections for 2-3 users goes to 100 active connections. and then server timeouts happen.

I then used IOC -autofac  to  resuse the same repository that has a datacontext. now tho i get an active connection on the SQL server per loggedin user plus one. 
I have never seen this before.

1. Why wouldnt Lin2sql not drop a connection when not in use?
2. would calling a stored procedure in an ajax call in a loggedin session creat an a new active connection?
3. Could a Stored Procedure with loops and or a waitfor hold open a connection??

Comment: Need to add some code. You're not releasing connections somewhere...

Comment: Isnt LINQ 2 SQL supposed only open a connection when need 'cause it is lazy loaded. Also it closes connections when no longer needed even befor it is disposed of?? right??

Comment: That is not correct. Lazy loading has nothing to do with when a connection is opened or closed.

Comment: @Randy -  Well the truth is linq to sql should only open when needed and then close. Regardless whether the .net object here the repository class is disposed or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection associated with an L2S context object will only get dropped when the connection object is disposed, either by you or by the GC. It will not get dropped because of inactivity.

If you try to create your context object in a Using statement, they will get disposed appropriately.

Comment: When do you use the datacontext in a repository pattern with the using statement????

Comment: @Joe: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357615/how-do-i-correctly-dispose-a-linq-to-sql-datacontext-in-a-repository

Comment: I do implement disposable on the repository but I did not a)wrap the repository in using nor b) have autofac limited the lifetime