# Getting around "DataContext accessed after Dispose" error in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 action that looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using(var db = new MyDataContext())
        {
            var welcomeSnippet = "test";
            var articles = db.Posts.Where(p => p.DateOfPublish <= DateTime.Now).Take(5).ToList();
            return View(new HomeViewModel()
            {
                Articles = articles,
                WelcomeSnippet = welcomeSnippet
            });
        }
    }
```

The view includes the following code:

```
<%foreach (var item in Model.Articles)
{%>
     <div class="article" id="<%=item.PostID %>">
          <!-- some properties -->
          <div class="tags">tags: <i><%foreach (var tag in item.PostTags.ToList())
                                        { %><%=Html.Encode(tag.Tag.TagName.Trim())%> <%} %></i>
          </div>
     </div>
<% } %>
```

I'm accessing `item.PostTags`, which is obtained through my DataContext. Here, I'm essentially using lazy-loading, but I'm getting an error: my DataContext is already disposed when it comes time to list those PostTags.

**How can I load such data before my DataContext is disposed?**

Comment: Don't dispose the DataContext. See http://leedumond.com/blog/about-disposing-the-datacontext/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821574/c-linq-to-sql-should-datacontext-be-disposed-using-idisposable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options:

1) Manually Dispose of DC (e.g Application_EndRequest in Global.asax)

2) Eager load `item.Tags` in Controller:

```
using(var db = new MyDataContext())
        {
            var welcomeSnippet = "test";
            var articles = db.Posts.Include("PostTags").Where(p => p.DateOfPublish <= DateTime.Now).Take(5).ToList();

            return View(new HomeViewModel()
            {
                Articles = articles,
                WelcomeSnippet = welcomeSnippet
            });
        }
```

I would go option 2, as option 1 is risky without the use of a DI container. (which your obviously not using).

**EDIT**

Sorry - i thought you were using Entity Framework, here is the L2SQL equivalent of "eager loading":

You need to use **DataLoadOptions**

```
using(var db = new MyDataContext())
        {
            var dataLoadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
            dataLoadOptions.LoadWith<Post>(x => x.PostTags);
            db.LoadOptions = dataLoadOptions;

            var welcomeSnippet = "test";
            var articles = db.Posts.Where(p => p.DateOfPublish <= DateTime.Now).Take(5).ToList();

            return View(new HomeViewModel()
            {
                Articles = articles,
                WelcomeSnippet = welcomeSnippet
            });
        }
```

Comment: So for each property that I need to eager-load, I just do: `.Include("PropertyName")? Great!

This solves my short term needs, but I'll be sure to look into dependency injection.

Comment: Hmm... **`.Include()` isn't showing up in Intellisense**. Could you point me to an MSDN page that references it so that I can make sure I'm not doing something wrong?

Comment: Oh crap, hold on - your using L2SQL, i thought you were using Entity Framework. My bad. `Include` is EF-specific. Will update my answer.

Comment: No problem, I've already found the workaround: http://www.singingeels.com/Blogs/Nullable/2008/10/27/EntityFramework_Include_Equivalent_in_LINQ_to_SQL.aspx. When I upgrade to .NET 4, I'll probably switch to: http://damieng.com/blog/2010/05/21/include-for-linq-to-sql-and-maybe-other-providers or http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2010/11/06/include-linq-extension.aspx.

Comment: Yep - which is what i put in my edited answer. :) Advice - next project, use EF. L2SQL is basically obselete. (in MS eyes anyway)

Comment: Pleasure. It's basically the same concept as L2SQL (ORM), but a LOT more flexibility/options. Glad to help. :)